# Issues with exporting table data to excel using Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a report page which has two labels,two dropdowns,a command button and a table to display the data. 
The issue is,while exporting the data to excel, the labels and dropdowns are also getting exported along with the table.

How do I export just the table not any html controls?

Answer (score 3):

It's better export the contents of table to an excel file, by FileSystemObject.

for example :

```
    dim vPath , vRecordset
    vPath = "reports/" & objFileSystem.GetTempName & ".xls"
    set vRecordset= DBConnection.Execute(SqlQueryString)

    set objFileSystem = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set objFile= objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(vPath),8,true,-1)

    dim strHeader,strLine
    strHeader = "<table border=1><tr>"
    strLine = ""

    for each col in vRecordset.fields
        strHeader = strHeader &"<th bgcolor=#bed9fa><b>" & col.name & "</b></th>"
    next
    objFile.WriteLine strHeader & "</tr>"

    do while not vRecordset.eof
        strLine = "<tr>"
        for each col in vRecordset.fields
            strLine = strLine & "<td>" & col.value &  "</td>"
        next
        objFile.WriteLine strLine & "</tr>"
    vRecordset.movenext
    loop
    objFile.WriteLine "</table>"

    response.write "<a href='"& vPath &"'>report download</a>"
```

It will be more smooth for user downloading an existing file to responsing all contents of page directly.